# Show only parent category post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I want to show only parent category post. like i have create 1 category (pritesh : Parent category) in wordpress and add 2 post in this category the i have create another category (Nilesh - Child cateory) but this is the child category of first one and then i have add 2 more article in this category now i have run my code then when i use first category

========================================================================

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category_name'    => 'pritesh',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
); 



$output = '<ul>';
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Now i print $myposts variable then Nilesh category posts will showing. But i want only Pritesh category posts. How i do that. I have tried many code but not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'is_category()' or 'in_category()' just before echoing your post.

```
<?php
if ( in_category('fruit') ) {
    include 'single-fruit.php';
} elseif ( in_category('vegetables') ) {
    include 'single-vegetables.php';
} else {
    // Continue with normal Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // ...
}
?>
```

In your case :

```
<?php
if ( is_category('Nilesh') ) 
{
    // Continue with normal Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // ...
}
?>
```

For more information, check this out:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

Also [this support ticket](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-not-display-child-categories-posts-in-parent-category-archive).